# tempWord[0]='\0' Does not reset String somehow

Tags: c, string

I wrote a program in C, The expected result should be:

```
$ cat poem.txt

Said Hamlet to Ophelia,
I'll draw a sketch of thee,
What kind of pencil shall I use?
2B or not 2B? 

$ ./censor Ophelia < poem.txt

Said Hamlet to CENSORED,
I'll draw a sketch of thee,
What kind of pencil shall I use?
2B or not 2B?
```

But I got this:

```
$ ./censor Ophelia < poem.txt

Said Hamlet tomlet CENSORED,
I'lllia drawlia arawlia sketcha ofetcha theecha,
Whatcha kindcha ofndcha pencila shallla Ihallla usellla?
2Bsellla orellla notllla 2Botllla?
```

I use tempWord to store every word and compare it with the word that needs to be censored. Then I use `tempWord[0]='\0'` to reset the temp String, so that I can do another comparison. But it seems not working. Can anyone help?

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

int compareWord(char *list1, char *list2);
int printWord(char *list);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int character = 0;

    char tempWord[128];
    int count = 0;

    while (character != EOF) {
        character = getchar();

        if ((character <= 'z' && character >= 'a') ||
            (character <= 'Z' && character >= 'A') ||
            character == 39) {              
            tempWord[count] = character;
            count++;
        } else {
            if (count != 0 && compareWord(tempWord, argv[1])) {
                printf("CENSORED");
                count = 0;
                tempWord[0] = '\0';
            }

            if (count != 0 && !compareWord(tempWord, argv[1])) {
                printWord(tempWord);
                count = 0;
                tempWord[0] = '\0';
            }

            if (count == 0) {
                printf("%c", character);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int printWord(char *list) {

    // print function
}

int compareWord(char *list1, char *list2) {
         // compareWord function
}
```

Comment: Suggest you use a debugger to trace the execution of your program line by line.

Comment: `strlen()` expects as C-"string", that means in *any* case it *relies* on the `char`-array being passed to be `0`-terminated

Comment: @alk: You are correct. If we use memset to set all position to null. Then this problem also will be cleared.

Comment: @sureshkumar: ... the essential question being still open is when and where to do this.

Comment: @alk, very insightful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- You do not test for end of file at the right spot: if `getc()` returns `EOF`, you should exit the loop immediately instead of processing `EOF` and exiting at the next iteration. The classic C idiom to do this is:

  ```
  while ((character = getchar()) != EOF) {
      ...
  ```
- For portability and readability, you should use `isalpha()` from `<ctype.h>` to check if the byte is a letter and avoid hardcoding the value of the value of the apostrophe as `39`, use `'\''` instead.
- You have a potential buffer overflow when storing the bytes into the `tempWord` array. You should compare the offset with the buffer size.
- You do not null terminate `tempWord`, hence the `compareWord()` function cannot determine the length of the first string. The behavior is undefined.
- You do not check if a command line argument was provided.
- The second test is redundant: you could just use an `else` clause.
- You have undefined behavior when printing the contents of `tempWord[]` because of the lack of null termination. This explains the unexpected behavior, but you might have much worse consequences.
- `printWord` just prints a C string, use `fputs()`.
- The `compWord` function is essentially the same as `strcmp(a, b) == 0`.

Here is a simplified and corrected version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char tempWord[128];
    size_t count = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isalpha(c) || c == '\'') {
            if (count < sizeof(tempWord) - 1) {
                tempWord[count++] = c;
            }
        } else {
            tempWord[count] = '\0';
            if (argc > 1 && strcmp(tempWord, argv[1]) == 0) {
                printf("CENSORED");
            } else {
                fputs(tempWord, stdout);
            }
            count = 0;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** chux rightfully commented that the above code does not handle 2 special cases:

- words that are too long are truncated in the output.
- the last word is omitted if it falls exactly at the end of file.

I also realized the program does not handle the case of long words passed on the command line.

Here is a different approach without a buffer that fixes these shortcomings:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *word = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "";
    int count = 0;
    int c;

    for (;;) {
        c = getchar();
        if (isalpha(c) || c == '\'') {
            if (count >= 0 && (unsigned char)word[count] == c) {
                count++;
            } else {
                if (count > 0) {
                    printf("%.*s", count, word);
                }
                count = -1;
                putchar(c);
            }
        } else {
            if (count > 0) {
                if (word[count] == '\0') {
                    printf("CENSORED");
                } else {
                    printf("%.*s", count, word);
                }
            }
            if (c == EOF)
                break;
            count = 0;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now, everything is much clearer. thank you so much for the suggestion.

Comment: Very nice, but I think it might not print the _last_ word - and it is limited to 128 sized string. Still well explains OP's issues.

Comment: @chux: thank you for pointing 2 remaining flaws. I was conscious of the second, but overlooked the potential omission of the last word of a non newline terminated file. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Nice.  I was suspecting this was one of those times to not use `while ((character = getchar()) != EOF)`.

Comment: @chux: I came up with a simpler solution that can handle arbitrary long words.

Comment: Very nice - even uses the subtle needed cast in `word[count] == (char)c`. Note: in a computer grave yard, `char` may be signed and have only 255 valid values and a trap value.  `(unsigned char) word[count] == c` avoids that trap.

Comment: @chux: indeed, there is always one more bug... On the DS9K, one could pass a command line argument whose length exceeds the range of `int` causing undefined behavior on carefully crafted input :(

Comment: @chux: more seriously, digits should probably not be considered separators.

Comment: Could use  `size_t` and `SIZE_MAX` rather than `int`, `-1`.  [TTFN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTFN)

Comment: @chux. Yes, and I would change the `printf` for an `fwrite`

Answer (score 1):

```
tempWord[0] = '\0';
```

It will not reset the variable to null. It just assign the '\0' to the first position. But The values which are assigned  are still in memory only. Only the first position is assigned to '\0'. So, to reset the character array try the below.

```
memset(tempWord, 0, 128);
```

Add the above line instead of your `tempWord[0] = '\0'`.

And also this will solves you don't need to add the '\0' at end of each word. This itself will work. But for the first time your have to reset the character array using the same memset function. Before entering to the loop you have to set the tempWord to null using the memset function.

Answer (score 1):

Using tempWord[0]='\0' will not reset the whole array, just the first element. Looking at your code, there are 2 ways you could go forward, either reset the whole array by using `memset`:

```
memset(tempWord, 0, sizeof tempWord);
```

or

```
memset(tempWord, 0, 128);
```

(or you can only clear it by the size of last word, also it needs string.h which you have already included),

Or you could just set the element after the length of 'current word' to be '\0' (ex, if current word is `the` then set `tempWord[3]='\0'`, since `strlen` checks the string till null char only) which can be placed before those 2 ifs checking if the strings are equal or not, your new while loop will look like this:

```
{
        character = getchar();

        if((character<='z' && character>='a')||(character<='Z' && character>='A')||character == 39)
        {               
            tempWord[count]=character;
            count++;

        }else {
            tempWord[count]='\0';

            if(count!=0 && compareWord(tempWord, argv[1]))
            {

                printf("CENSORED");
                count=0;


            }

            if(count!=0 && !compareWord(tempWord, argv[1]))
            {

                printWord(tempWord);
                count=0;

            }

            if (count==0)
            {
                printf("%c", character);
            }
        }
    }
```

(it works, tested)

Comment: @sureshkumar i was typing the 2nd part which doesn't need the use of memset, and i was gathering where to put the value so it took time to post...